# How to update a menu item in a status menu on Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm a very beginner in Objective-C and in Mac development. I've searched this site for the answer I'm seeking, but due to a big ignorance I could not understand how this should be done.

The following piece of code implements a menu in Mac status bar, near the battery, wifi, etc icons on the top right of the screen.

If the user disconnects a device from the computer the method `sayAdapterIsConnected` is called with one boolean argument. Depending on that argument, one of the menu items, in this case the `enabledOption`, should get disabled. I mean, the menu item should be enabled or disabled.

This works only if the menu is closed. If the `statusMenu` is opened, it is not updated.

I know there is a way to update an open `statusItem` menu. Wifi status icon updates its networks while the menu is open.

```
@interface ENHeringAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSStatusItem * statusItem;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *enabledOption;

@end

@implementation ENHeringAppDelegate

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:_statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"TEST"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

- (void)sayAdapterIsConnected:(bool)connected {
    if (connected)
        [self.enabledOption setEnabled:true];
    else
        [self.enabledOption setEnabled:false];
}

@end
```

Comment: You say you "already tried many solutions from this forum, but none of them worked for me." Please explain which solutions you tried and what the results were so we don't repeat ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NSMenu isn't needed here. You also don't need the setMenu: call.

Here's a working example:

### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface KBCAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
  NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (IBAction)update:(id)sender;

@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation KBCAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  // Insert code here to initialize your application

  statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
  [statusItem setTitle:@"TEST"];
  [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
  [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
  [statusItem setTarget:self];

}

- (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
  if (!statusItem.isEnabled) {
    [statusItem setEnabled:true];
  } else {
    [statusItem setEnabled:false];
  }
}

@end
```

That's all you need to do. (I made `update:` an IBAction, but a void function like what you show would work too)

P.S.
Make us nitpickers happy and always use braces in your if/then statements, even if there is only one line. :)